# Converting string to timestamp?

Tags: string, timestamp

I have a xml file in which date is represented as this: "2010-07-10T14:46:00.000Z"
Im parsing it and fetching it as string.

I need to convert it into timestamp or date format to store in db. How do i do it?

Please help.

Comment: Please indicate the language you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use PHP:
You can use the function DateTime::createFromFormat(string $format, string $time)
try the following:

```
$timestamp = str_ireplace(array('T', 'Z'), '', "2010-07-10T14:46:00.000Z");  
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-d H:i:s.u ', $timestamp);  
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Please see the documentation of [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) for the correct format string.

Answer (score 0):

generally you need to use strptime() related functions, that come from standard C library.